# camera calibration and ROI

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-info-manager, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i've just a litte question regarding calibration of a camera and ROI.
If i have calibration values for a camera and change the roi?
Does this affect the calibration values in anyway and do i have to do the calibration again?

I thought that i don't have to recalibrate the camera if i just change the ROI since it can be calculated based on the calibration values of the full resolution image.

The reason why i'm asking is the camera_info_manager.
I've implemented it and it works quite good.

However if change the ROI it does not affect the camera_info message in terms of ROI.
I can either add the ROI to my camera_name and force the user to recalibrate the camera every time a different ROI is set or i modify my camera_info message from manager regarding ROI values.

what's the best solution?

cheers Mimax

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11613/camera-calibration-and-roi/) by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [REP-0104](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html) specification supports using the full resolution calibration with a cropped image.

The `CameraInfo` returned by `camera_info_manager` contains default operational parameters, including binning and ROI values. That works unmodified if your camera is publishing the full-resolution image for which it was calibrated.

To publish a cropped image, add the appropriate ROI parameters to the `CameraInfo` message before publishing it. You can look at the `camera1394` driver for an [example of this logic](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/camera1394/html/driver1394_8cpp_source.html#l00201).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-21**:
Fuerte final freeze is coming soon, Feb. 15th. To change the API for that release we need the new interface defined, so please file an enhancement ticket right away: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=image_common&type=enhancement&image_common

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-21**:
Thanks for that hint. I'll definitely do this

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-21**:
Adding some method like setOperationalParameters() to camera_info_manager seems reasonable. If you have suggestions, please open an enhancement ticket. We could add it for Fuerte.

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-20**:
This way i could skip the comparison of roi values every time publishing an image just modify the origin camera_info_message of the camera_info_manager

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-20**:
Thanks Jack. That is about the way i wanted to implement it. However wouldn't it make sense to have an member method in the camera_info_manager for changing the operation parameters which can be called if  I change ROI or Binning by a service call.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that setting a ROI changes where the origin of the image is, I believe that the only calibration parameters affected should be the principal point, which is part of the intrinsic camera matrix (K).

Setting a ROI is effectively pretending your imaging sensor is smaller, so nothing else should change.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1